# the server responded with a status of 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

Tags: php, apache

I am working one of larvel application with file uploading.
If I try to upload 500mb video then I get the following error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 413
>   (Request Entity Too Large)

Comment: try and have a look at this : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/413-request-entity-too-large-nginx162

Comment: thanks for your reply but i dont know where i can find this " /etc/nginx/nginx.conf" i have cPanel of site on that it is not,will you help to find this file.

Comment: if you have FTP access to your site you should be able to find it.

Comment: I have but this file is not there,my site is running on apache not with nginx.

Comment: You can check following Answer. This helped me.
http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/413-request-entity-too-large-error-with-uploading-a-file